# Filter date given start and end date columns

Tags: mysql

I am given two columns `start_date` and `end_date`. Is is possible in MySQL to use where clause to filter for specific date that is in the range of those two fields? Could you provide me with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, we have `between` operator.

```
SELECT date_to_filter
FROM table_dates
WHERE :date_to_filter_bind BETWEEN start_date AND end_date;
```

in `:date_to_filter_bind` you put the date that you want.